Under what circumstances can a CSS rule with specificity 0-0-1 override one with specificity 0-1-0?
In the screenshot below, you can see that a font-family declaration with a rule specificity 0-0-1 is taking precedence over one with specificity 0-1-0.
My understanding is that order of rules only matters when specificity is equal, which is not the case here.
Notably, even adding !important to the class name selector has no effect on the outcome.
Chrome and Firefox both exhibit the same behavior here, so I assume whatever is happening is to spec.
Under what circumstances would the behavior in the screenshot be expected?


What happens if you only target html in the selector?

@htor then the problem goes away. See Raphael Oluwasanmi's answer for the explanation on why this was happening. The font-family in the class name selector was being applied to  and being inherited by , so the rule being directly applied to  takes precedence. Just a brain fart on my part.
